# error: conflicting types for 'strdup'!

Tags: c, strdup

This is program in book “The c programming language”.
There is an error:conflicting types for 'strdup'! When encounter function 'strdup'.But if you change 'strdup' to other name, for example 'strdu', the error will disappear.
**I don't know WHY？** By the way, I use code::blocks as my IDE.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXWORD 100

struct tnode {
    char *word;           
    int count;           
    struct tnode *left;   
    struct tnode *right; 
};

struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *, char *);
struct tnode *talloc(void);

void treeprint(struct tnode *);
int getword(char *, int);
char *strdup(char *);

/*  word frequency count */
int main()
{
    struct tnode *root;
    char word[MAXWORD];

    root = NULL;
    while (getword(word, MAXWORD) != EOF)
        if (isalpha(word[0]))
            root = addtree(root, word);
    treeprint(root);
    return 0;
}
/* addtree: add a node with w, at or below p */
struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *p, char *w)
{
    int cond;
    if (p == NULL) {       /* a new word has arrived */
        p = talloc();      /* make a new node */
        p->word = strdup(w);
        p->count = 1;
        p->left = p->right = NULL;
    } else if ((cond = strcmp(w, p->word)) == 0)
        p->count++;        /* repeated word */
    else if (cond < 0)     /* less than into left subtree */
        p->left = addtree(p->left, w);
    else                   /* greater than into right subtree */
        p->right = addtree(p->right, w);
    return p;
};

/* treeprint: in-order print of tree p */
void treeprint(struct tnode *p)
{
    if (p != NULL) {
        treeprint(p->left);
        printf("%4d %s\n", p->count, p->word);
        treeprint(p->right);
    }
}

/* talloc: make a tnode */
struct tnode *talloc(void)
{
    return (struct tnode *) malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
};

char *strdup(char *s)  /* make a duplicate of s */
{
    char *p;

    p = (char *) malloc(sizeof(strlen(s)) + 1);
    if (p != NULL)
        strcmp(p, s);
    return p;
}
.... some other function ....
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot have a function of your own whose name starts with `str`. That whole "namespace" is reserved, in C.

In this case, `strdup()` is a standard function from `<string.h>`, which your function declaration collides with.

Note that it's not enough to stop using `<string.h>`, the name is still reserved so you cannot validly use it.

A couple of further notes:

1. The input is not written to, so it should be a  `const` pointer.
2. [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).
3. Your `strdup()` workalike is horribly broken, it calls `strcmp()` when it means `strcpy()`.
4. Your use of `sizeof(strlen(s))` is totally wrong and will cause massive problems even if you fix the `strcmp()`/`strcpy()` problem.

A reasonable `strdup()` implementation is:

```
char * my_strdup(const char *s)
{
  char *r = NULL;
  if(s != NULL)
  {
    const size_t size = strlen(s) + 1;
    if((r = malloc(size)) != NULL)
      memcpy(r, s, size);
  }
  return r;
}
```

I use `memcpy()` since I know the length, it can be quicker.

Comment: Plus, `s` should be declared as `const char *` since it doesn't modify the string's contents (**Edit:** Ninja'd by unwind's edit which added code).

Comment: @Medinoc That's true of course (and was "automatically" in my code) but I made an explicit mention, too. Thanks.

Comment: @unwind  I thought little about "namespace", and obviously I am  not familiar with the <string.h>. Thank you for telling me those and the further notes!

Answer (score 2):

strdup is allready defined in string.h. Just rename your function.